# react i18next use a translation inside my custome formatter

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I am tring to creat my own format and use inside the formatter in translation from my common:

```
// after i18next.init(options);
i18next.services.formatter.add('balbal', (value, lng, options) => {
 return i18next.t("mykey",{ ns: 'common' })
});
```

All i am getting is mykey and not the translation, Any solution how to access my translation

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible codesandbox example or similar?